# Best transformation for a heavy tailed distribution

Tags: heavy-tailed

I am anaylsing a data set, which displays a heavy-tailed distribution when examined on a Quantile-Quantile plot. What is (or are) the best transformation(s) to use to correct a dataset with a heavy-tailed distribution?

Comment: What do you want to correct? What makes you think there's something that needs to be corrected?

Comment: Some distributions are just heavy tailed, like the mass distribution in a cat.  My cat would be pretty unhappy if I attempted to "correct" this.

Comment: I'm with kodiologist -- what's the problem with a heavy tailed distribution? Even if there is a problem, why would you transform rather than do something else?

Comment: Do you have data to share, or at least some plots? What do you want to achieve with your analysis,  why do you care about normality?

Comment: What do you want to acheive for this data? What is your model? Why do you think tails is wrong then you would like to correct it? Did you have any ideas about transformation? It is good idea to ask yourself many questions before asking this will help you to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the series with the natural logarithm. Alternatively, some of the literature looking at the determinants of net worth have used the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation. (See [Pence 2006](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~scholz/Teaching_742/Pence.pdf)) It has the advantage of accommodating zero and negative values.